# GUI C debugger for OSx Lion

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

Does anyone know a good GUI C debugger for Lion, I looked into DDD since thats what I use in linux but i couldn't find a clear way to install it for Lion.

Comment: What's wrong with Xcode?

Comment: I'm sorry, but questions about programming should be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) instead of Ask Different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install ddd you can do it via installing the Macports package manager http://www.macports.org/

Also You can use the GUI implementation of gdb  in Apple's Xcode. You just need to add your source in to an Xcode project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on Macports, it really helps coming from the world of linux